# Android: Suggestion required for Update recycler view on item selected from spinner

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to recycler view. My requirement is as follows:
- I have to call a web service that will give two arrays. One with data I need to show in the list. For this purpose, I am using `RecyclerView`. The other array is of statuses, which I am showing in spinner. This web service is paginated. I have added pagination and it is working fine.
- When user selects some other element from the spinner, again I have to make a web service call and recycler view data should change.
Currently, in case of pagination I am doing following, once I get more data from the successive pages:

```
mAccountListingsAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(mAccountListingsAdapter.getItemCount(), mListings.size() - 1);
```

And, when I change data from spinner, I am doing following:

```
mListings.clear();//Clear the data set

mAccountListingsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//Call notify data set changed on recycler view adapter

getAccountListings();//Fetch new data from the web service and display in recycler view
```

But, it is suggested that, instead of calling notifyDataSetChanged() directly on recycler view adapter, one should call specific notifyXXX method, to avoid performance and animations issues.

So, I am under doubt, if I am doing right to notify recycler view adapter in `onItemSelected()` of spinner, or it should be changed.

P.S. I tried following in the `onItemSelected`:

```
int size = mListings.size();
mListings.clear();
mAccountListingsAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size - 1);
```

But then it crashed, with following exception:

```
03-02 12:59:41.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4270): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 4(offset:0).state:5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `notifyItemRangeRemoved` is the correct method to use here, but the value you are passing for second parameter is wrong. As per the doc, the second parameter is number of items removed from data set, what you are passing is the position of last item removed.

[image]

So the below code should work fine

```
int size = mListings.size();
mListings.clear();
mAccountListingsAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
```

For more info refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeRemoved(int,%20int)

Comment: +1 My mistake Abhishek - I started writing my answer and took a break before finally posting it. Didn't occur to me that someone else might have posted an answer in the meanwhile. For now, I'll keep the answer posted for the other info it provides.

Comment: @Vikram Sure. No Problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the method definition for `notifyItemRangeRemoved (int, int)` is:

```
public final void notifyItemRangeRemoved (int positionStart, int itemCount)
```

The second argument is the `count`, not `positionEnd`. In your case you are passing `size - 1` as the second argument, when it should be `size` itself.

```
int size = mListings.size();
mListings.clear();
// should be notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size)
mAccountListingsAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size - 1);
```

Second, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is frowned upon because it triggers a  rebind and relayout of all visible views. In your case, where the number of visible items is zero, I don't see why `notifyDataSetChanged()` would degrade performance. If you are animating the removal of items, go with `notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size)`. Else, its quite alright to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` over here.